# Connect to DB2 (change from MySQL) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, db2

I have a code written in PHP that currently connects to an MySQL database. I want to change that connection to DB2 and it currently looks like this:

```
$this->connection = db2_connect($this->db_host, $this->username, $this->pwd);
if(!$this->connection) {  
    $this->HandleDBError("failed to connect to database");
    return false;
}

if(!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection)) {
    $this->HandleDBError('Failed to select database '.$this->database.' See if the database name is correct ');
    return false;
}

if(!mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'",$this->connection)) {
    $this->HandleDBError('Error setting utf8 encoding');
    return false;
}

return true;
```

As you can see, I have made a small change (`db2_connect`). What is the equivalent of `mysql_select_db` and `mysql_query` for DB2? (Yes, I know some of the MySQL statements have been updated, but will it still work? What changes need to be done?)

Answer (score 0):

1) The 1st parameter of [db2_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php) is called $database. That should give you a hint of what's the equivalent of `mysql_select_db()`

2) The direct equivalent of `maysql_query()` is [db2_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-exec.php), but you should consider using prepared statements if you have dynamic parameters. See example in php documentation on [db2_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-prepare.php):

```
<?php
$animals = array(
    array(0, 'cat', 'Pook', 3.2),
    array(1, 'dog', 'Peaches', 12.3),
    array(2, 'horse', 'Smarty', 350.0),
);

$insert = 'INSERT INTO animals (id, breed, name, weight)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $insert);
if ($stmt) {
    foreach ($animals as $animal) {
        $result = db2_execute($stmt, $animal);
    }
}
?>
```